# Escaping single quotes for an SQL query in ArcPy

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-pro, sql, error-000358

I have some data with strings containing single quotes (') and can't figure out a way to pass that string into an SQL query in `arcpy.analysis.Select()`.

The SQL query running on a feature class in a GDB requires single quotes for values e.g. Query: `"Name = 'Bob'"`. I want to pass in a name such as "exam'ple2" into the query.

The "Definition Query" in ArcGIS Pro resolves this by using '' (2x single quotes). See below for an example of a working query:

```
NAME IN ('example1','exam''ple2','''examp''le3')
```

--- each ' in input is replaced with ''

However, this is not a working option for a python script since each pair of quotes (' ') is treated as a separate string, and all my attempts end up with strings encapsulated by double-quotes.

Here's the code I'm trying to run:

```
import arcpy

nametuple = ('example1',"exam'ple2","'examp'le3")

arcpy.analysis.Select("Areas","test",f"NAME IN {nametuple}")

ERROR 000358: Invalid expression NAME IN ('example1',"exam'ple2","'examp'le3")
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just ran a test using ArcGIS Pro 2.7.2 and code like this worked for me from the Python window:

```
arcpy.analysis.Select("TestFC","TestFC_Sel","Name IN ('Dzawada''enuxw First Nation')")
```

Based on that learning I wrote a short Python script to test the same syntax in IDLE:

```
import arcpy

arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True
arcpy.env.workspace = r"C:\temp\TestProject.gdb"

arcpy.analysis.Select("TestFC","TestFC_Sel",
                      "Name IN ('Dzawada''enuxw First Nation')")
```

That worked too.

I expanded my test to include two other values in the Name field:

```
import arcpy

arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True
arcpy.env.workspace = r"C:\temp\TestProject.gdb"

arcpy.analysis.Select("TestFC","TestFC_Sel",
                      "Name IN ('''Namgis Nation','Dzawada''enuxw First Nation','Gwa''Sala-''Nakwaxda''xw Nation')")
```

That worked too.

Prompted by [@Vince's comment](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/392583/escaping-single-quotes-for-an-sql-query-in-arcpy#comment642415_392585) I also ran a third test where the values are provided in a list before building the expression:

```
import arcpy

arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True
arcpy.env.workspace = r"C:\temp\TestProject.gdb"

namesList = ["'Namgis Nation","Dzawada'enuxw First Nation","Gwa'Sala-'Nakwaxda'xw Nation"]


arcpy.analysis.Select("TestFC","TestFC_Sel",
                      "Name in ('{:s}')".format("','".join([x.replace("'","''") for x in namesList])))
```

That worked too.

For a fourth test I used a slightly different Python string formatting style and included a double-quoted string with no single quote embedded in it, and that worked too:

```
import arcpy

arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True
arcpy.env.workspace = r"C:\temp\TestProject.gdb"

namesList = ["c","'Namgis Nation","Dzawada'enuxw First Nation","Gwa'Sala-'Nakwaxda'xw Nation"]


arcpy.analysis.Select("TestFC","TestFC_Sel",
                      "Name in ('{}')".format("','".join([x.replace("'","''") for x in namesList])))
```

Consequently, I am currently not able to reproduce the problem using my understanding from your description of it.